# Exporting group contacts to an excel file

Tags: contacts, export

How do I export a group to an excel file?  Pretty standard.  Wanting to export email as well as name, mailing address, city, postal code.

Thank you,
Shara

Using Wordpress

Comment: In general it is useful to add which version of CiviCRM you are using and what your CMS is, although possibly not so important for this question

Answer (score 4):

The User Guide has instructions and screenshots here for exporting contacts: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/exporting-your-contacts/

Search for the contacts and select the `Export Contacts` action from the drop-down list.